# How to implement a booking structure and query which minimize contention between customers

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm looking for the best way to implement a concert hall booking data structure and algorithm which will:

- minimize the contention/wait between parallel customers
- achieve the best performance

The pre conditions are:

- The data structure must have predefined entries (eg. seat 1, seat 2..., seat 1000)
- Customer can book more than 1 seat
- Customer cannot choose their seats
- The algorithm should be in JDBC

For instance I'm stuck with the below implementation.

The data structure has a `SEATS` table with a `BOOKED` column. At first, the table contains N rows with the `BOOKED` column set to `false`. The booking pseudo-algorithm is the following:

```
ps = statement("SELECT * FROM SEATS
WHERE BOOKED = false
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED")

ps.setFetchSize(min(seatsToBook, 50));

while(seats.size() < seatsToBook){
    seats.add(ps.next())
}

// Update per slice of 1000 to avoid IN limitation
statement("UPDATE SEATS SET BOOKED = true WHERE ID in slice(seats,1000)");
```

Is there better solution ?

Thanks!

Comment: Just some questions regarding your terminology; i. By "parallel" customers, do you mean multiple concurrent customers? ii. What is a "slice"? iii. Is there a maximum number of seats a customer can book?

Comment: i. I mean concurrent customers. ii. The Oracle `IN` clause cannot contain more than 1000 values. I slice the `seats` collections into sub collection of 1000 values. iii. yes, but i'm not sure it should be part of the problem. The number of seats is overprovisionned and the limit will be on the booking request

Comment: How many seats in total (roughly). I cannot imagine more than around 100k, right?

Comment: Is this a real application or a school project?

Comment: This is a real project. The project is not about a concert hall booking application but about a registered mail number booking application. It is easier to explain with the concert hall analogy. The concert hall can have more than 100k seats

Comment: OK, so how many? What order of magnitude?

Comment: 500k seats and a booking requests will be limited to 1000 seats.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138111/discussion-between-nicolas-labrot-and-bobc).